# Can PostgreSQL service in OpenShift cluster receive external traffic via exposed route

Tags: postgresql, openshift, sni

Is it possible to run PostgreSQL as a service inside an OpenShift cluster and get [external traffic](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/dev_guide/expose_service/index.html) to it via an exposed route (the recommended default way for communicating from the outside)?

The OpenShift 3.9 [documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/dev_guide/expose_service/expose_internal_ip_router.html#getting-traffic-into-cluster-router) states this:

> A router is configured to accept external requests and proxy them
>   based on the configured routes. This is limited to
>   HTTP/HTTPS(SNI)/TLS(SNI), which covers web applications.

PostgreSQL can to SSL and it can be configured to listen on port 443 (HTTPS), but I think it [cannot](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/9af47a45-f92d-7ede-2d71-222ba24447eb%402ndquadrant.com) do SNI yet. I would only run a single pod behind the service, so load balancing should not cause issues. If feasible, I would expect to connect into the cluster and to the service with `psql -h ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come to the (preliminary) conclusion that OpenShift [port forwarding](https://blog.openshift.com/openshift-connecting-database-using-port-forwarding/) (`oc port-forward`) offers the best way (well ... :) forward in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `LoadBalancer` service which will create a load balancer dedicated to just your pods, and this load balancer accepts TCP based traffic: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/admin_guide/tcp_ingress_external_ports.html#unique-external-ips-ingress-traffic-configure-service

So something like

`oc expose dc postgres --type=LoadBalancer --name=postgres-lb`

Would get you a publicly accessible PostgreSQL DB

Comment: Promising: I can now `ping postgres-lb.my-cluster`, but `psql -h postgres-lb.my-cluster` still does not work ("connection timed out"). The PostgreSQL logfile remains silent, so I'm quite sure this is not an issue with `pg_hba.conf` inside the container. `oc get svc` reports `PORT(S) 5432:30607/TCP` for my service. Have you actually tried this with PostgreSQL and can you give further advise on how to proceed?

Comment: I thought the problem might be that OpenShift software-defined network (SDN) is acting as firewall and only permitting access to container ports 80 and 443. I tried letting PostgreSQL listen on port 443, but this fails because the container must not run as root inside OpenShift. So this is still a half-baked solution.